Binding to DataGrid
I have two classes - Object and Parameters.
Public class Object
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    ......
    public List<Parameters> Paramlist { get; set; } = new List<Parameters>();
}

Public class Parameters
{   
    public string parName { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }   
}

There are about 40 types of Objects. Each Object type has multiple parameters, the common for all of them are listed in Object Class. However, each type also has it's own parameters. That's why I am using the List.
Now User can pick  what kind of objects he wants to see in DataGrid. And then he can pick what kind of parameters he wants to see.
So only one DataGrid column is defined - ObjectName (Instance name). Others are added in runtime like this
 MainDataGrid.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn
 {
     Header = _parameter,
     Binding = new System.Windows.Data.Binding(_parameter),
     //_parameter is string received from user by picking one of the parameters in another DataGrid

 });
  

And it works, but only for the parameters listed in Object class.
Now I want to Bind also the other parameters. Basically go through each instance in DataGrid and if the instance has the parameter in the List, Bind the value from the list to a new column.
I don't necessarily need it to be List, that was the first idea i worked with. Obviously not a very good one.
Thanks for any suggestions.

Basically go through each instance in DataGrid and if the instance has the parameter in the List, Bind the value from the list to a new column. - why would you need to do that manually? a column typically only has the member and it will automagically resolve that member to the instance of the row, there should be no manual work needed to do this. https://i.sstatic.net/IxbQDPMW.png

You should not manually create the columns of the DataGrid. Just enable column auto-generation (it's enabled by default) and when the user completes his selection you create a DataTable from the collected information. Then bind the DataGrid.ItemsSource to this DataTable.

Yes, you are right I meant it what I want to happen. My Bad. I Wasn't sure how exactly describe my issue. User will pick Parameter Name in another DataGrid, the name will be added to the header and value of that parameter in List of each instance will be binded. If the instance does not have the parameter it will be blank.

but again, this should already work as described out of the box. just create the columns AS you are already doing and it should work. where is your problem? here a sample with "instance does not have parameter" - https://i.sstatic.net/2fsVQlSM.png

here a code behind solution: https://i.sstatic.net/IYniRGiW.png

@RandRandom Okay right now I feel like my brain just been broken, but I don't see how this could work for me. Maybe I will explain further my situation. I have a table containing columns like ID, Name, Value... etc. Then there is a column called parName. In the table each instance of some objects is written about tens to hundreds of times. Every value like Name or ID is the same, BUT the parName is always different (same as value). So I read the table to observable collection of type Object (add instance only 1 time) and read all the different params and values for this instance to list.

@RandRandom What I understood from this pic is that you created different class for each type of object. But I have around 40 types of objects and in total around 2000 different parameters. So I'm afraid, that if I understand your solution correctly, this would not work for me.

@BionicCode Thank you for your idea, I don't really have experience with DataTable so I will look into it

But I have around 40 types of objects and? if 1 or 2 or 5 or 40? what's the issue? and in total around 2000 different parameters some question here and? if 1 or 2 or 5 or 2000? what's the issue? - if you want to have a datagrid with 2000 columns/parameters and do it, that doesn't invalidate the solution provided. all you need to have is 1) a list of instances (containing of x different types, no one cares) 2) a list of parameters (to create x amount of columns) - thats all I am doing, and I still believe thats all you need to do. so I am afraid to say, I still don't understand your problem

so maybe my brain is broken, for further assistance I would ask you to provide an MRE https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example - so that I can actualy see and understand your issue

okay... I have an idea.. give me a sec

@iksd: So the ItemsSource property of the DataGrid is bound to an IEnumerable<Object> and you want add a column for each item in Paramlist?

@mm8 Yes, exactly, but the ParamList is different class (And also I can not adress it like object.ParamList.Value...)

@iksd: Then the dynamically added column should bind to Paramlist[i].Value where i is the index of the Parameters in the Paramlist collection.

After some struggle understanding your issue, I believe you are looking for Indexers
Here the documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/
Extend your Object class with an indexer
public class Object
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string this[string propertyName]
    {
        get
        {
            var parameterByName = Paramlist.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == propertyName);
            return parameterByName?.Value;
        }
        set
        {
            var parameterByName = Paramlist.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == propertyName);
            if (parameterByName == null)
                Paramlist.Add(new Parameters() { Name = propertyName, Value = value });
            else
                parameterByName.Value = value;
        }
    }

    public List<Parameters> Paramlist { get; set; } = new List<Parameters>();
}

By doing this you can create a Binding with the indexer syntax [PropertyName].
eg.
new System.Windows.Data.Binding("[MyProperty]")

Here a working sample:
MainWindow.xaml
<Window x:Class="WpfApp59.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Height="450"
        Width="800"
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}"
                  Name="MainDataGrid"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False">

            <!-- if you want to define the columns in xaml and not code behind -->
            <!--<DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding MySharedProperty}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding MyFooProperty}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding MyBarProperty}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding [MyMagic1]}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding [MyMagic2]}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding [MyMagic3]}" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>-->
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>

MainWindow.xaml.cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public IEnumerable<object> MyItems { get; set; } = new object[]
    {
        new Foo(){
            MySharedProperty = "I'm a Foo object.", 
            MyFooProperty = "Foo Property",
            ParamList = new List<Parameters>()
            {
                new Parameters(){Name = "MyMagic1", Value = "Foo Magic Value 1"},
                //new (){Name = "MyMagic2", Value = "Foo Magic Value 2"},
                new Parameters(){Name = "MyMagic3", Value = "Foo Magic Value 3"}
            }
        }, 
        new Bar(){
            MySharedProperty = "I'm a Bar object.", 
            MyBarProperty = "Bar Property",
            ParamList = new List<Parameters>()
            {
                new Parameters(){Name = "MyMagic1", Value = "Bar Magic Value 1"},
                new Parameters(){Name = "MyMagic2", Value = "Bar Magic Value 2"},
                //new (){Name = "MyMagic3", Value = "Foo Magic Value 3"}
            }
        }
    };

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        string[] parameters = new string[] {
            "MySharedProperty", 
            "MyFooProperty", 
            "MyBarProperty",
            "[MyMagic1]",
            "[MyMagic2]",
            "[MyMagic3]"
        };

        foreach (var parameter in parameters)
        {
            MainDataGrid.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn
            {
                Header = parameter,
                Binding = new System.Windows.Data.Binding(parameter),
            });
        }
    }
}

SharedObject.cs
public class SharedObject
{
    public string MySharedProperty { get; set; }

    public string this[string propertyName]
    {
        get
        {
            var parameterByName = ParamList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == propertyName);
            return parameterByName?.Value;
        }
        set
        {
            var parameterByName = ParamList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == propertyName);
            if (parameterByName == null)
                ParamList.Add(new Parameters() { Name = propertyName, Value = value });
            else
                parameterByName.Value = value;
        }
    }

    public List<Parameters> ParamList { get; set; }
}

Foo.cs
public class Foo : SharedObject
{
    public string MyFooProperty { get; set; }
}

Bar.cs
public class Bar : SharedObject
{
    public string MyBarProperty { get; set; }
}

Parameters.cs
public class Parameters
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

Result of the sample should be:


Thank you, this seems like it could work. Just trying it, however I am having issues with C# version, because it seems that some of that is not supported in C# 7.3 which I am using and so far I was not able to change it. I will sort this out, try it and let you know. Thanks

I tried your solution in testing app and it seems like it is working. But I was not successful to use it in my live code because I am using Observable collections and I was not able to cast everything to objects so far. Once I will be done I will mark it as solved. Thank you

Got to it and the issue was between the keyboard and the chair. Thanks for the patience and solution.

To simplify data handling and view generation you should use a DataTable and configure the DataGrid to auto-generate columns.
You then collect the information from the user (parameter types and objects) and create a data view using the DataTable. Then bind the DataGrid.ItemsSource to this DataTable:
ParameterType.cs
// Consider using an enum instead
public class ParameterType
{
  public string Name { get; }
}

Parameter.cs
public class Parameter
{  
  public ParameterType { get; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string Value { get; set; }   
}

MainWindow.xaml
<Window x:Name="VisualRoot">
  <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=VisualRoot, Path=TableData}" />
</Window>

MainWindow.xaml.cs
partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  public static readonly DependencyProperty TableDataProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "TableData", 
    typeof(DataTable),
    typeof(MainWindow));

  public DataTable TableData 
  {
    get => (DataTable)GetValue(TableDataProperty);
    set => SetValue(TableDataProperty, value);
  }

  private void CreateTableDataFromSelection(
    IEnumerable<Object> selectObjects, 
    IEnumerable<ParameterType> selectedParamterTypes)
  {
    var table = new DataTable();
    var column = new DataColumn("ObjectName", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add(column);

    IEnumerable<string> selectedParameterTypeNames = selectedParameterTypes.Select(parameterType => parameterType.Name);
    foreach (string parameterTypeName in selectedParameterTypeNames)
    {
      column = new DataColumn(parameterTypeName, typeof(string));
      table.Columns.Add(column);
    }

    foreach (Object value in selectedObjects)
    {
      IEnumerable<string> selectedObjectParameters = value.ParamList.Where(parameter => selectedParameterTypeNames.Contains(parameter.ParameterType.Name));

      DataRow row = table.NewRow();

      // If the object does not contain a parameter for a column, 
      // then this column remains empty
      foreach (Parameter selectedObjectParameter in selectedObjectParameters)
      {
        row[selectedParameter.Name] = selectedParameter.Value;
      }
     
      table.Rows.Add(row);
    }

    this.TableData = table;
  }
}

